# Puppet — if condition according to current status of machine

Tags: puppet, manifest

I am trying to write an if clause to do something according to the current status of a machine. I understand according to puppet's philosophy catalogs evaluate and push to the machines before they run in machines.

To keep consistency I would like to use puppet instead of using custom scripts (like bash). I need this kind of behavior in puppet if it would be possible.

Here's an example: puppet agent runs every hour on a machine:

pulling a repo to see any new commit 
   - searching for a specific word in the repo 
   - if found: trigger some dependencies 
   - if not found: trigger other dependencies

My problem: 'If clause' already had evaluated in puppet server so there is not any way to make dependencies in the desired order according to the machine status.

Any idea?

Comment: Ordinarily you use a custom fact for this, but your given example is also something that would be handled by a CI tool i.e. Jenkins according to best practices, so giving a MCVE might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tested custom facts with no desired result. They still evaluate before receiving catalogs. e.g. vcsrepo module pulls the repo after reading custom facts so I can not change the dependencies order. I will try CI tool as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write an if clause to do something according to the
>   current status of a machine. I understand according to puppet's
>   philosophy catalogs evaluate and push to the machines before they run
>   in machines.

It's not just Puppet's *philosophy*, it's deeply ingrained into Puppet's *implementation*.

> To keep consistency I would like to use puppet instead of using custom
>   scripts (like bash). I need this kind of behavior in puppet if it
>   would be possible.
>
> Here's an example: puppet agent runs every hour on a machine:
>
> pulling a repo to see any new commit - searching for a specific word
>   in the repo - if found: trigger some dependencies - if not found:
>   trigger other dependencies

That's simply not going to happen in the general case, at least not without every single run logging resource failures.  If a resource is included in a node's catalog, such that it can be applied at all, then it *will* be applied unless it depends on another resource that fails.  You could conceivably build something around `Exec` resources set to be `refreshonly`, but then you're back around to a script.  Even in that case, to support an `if` / `else` style, as opposed to just `if`, you would surely need to implement a custom type to mediate the choice of which of two sets of resources to notify.

> My problem: 'If clause' already had evaluated in puppet server so
>   there is not any way to make dependencies in the desired order
>   according to the machine status.

If you can afford a moderate delay (bounded by your agent run interval) between the repo being pulled down and whatever other actions you want being performed, then I would suggest using a scheduled task (e.g. a `cron` job) to pull down the repository periodically and a custom fact to determine, based on the pre-run machine state, which alternative the catalog builder should exercise.  You can even manage configuring the cron job via Puppet.

If that's inadequate then doing the whole thing directly or indirectly via a scheduled task is probably your best alternative.

Comment: Thanks, John. As you suggested may the best way would be using a cron task to handle this kind of scenarios.